# SIFT Workstation v3 Rollback on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: forensics, ubuntu

I am a lawyer taking courses in Digital Forensics and also, quite new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general). I installed SIFT Workstation v3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation using the bash:

> wget --quiet -O - https://raw.github.com/sans-dfir/sift-bootstrap/master /bootstrap.sh | sudo bash -s -- -i -s -y

which I found in the SIFT Workstation download page.

Does anyone have an idea to uninstall the SIFT Workstation with a similar bash command?

Comment: Note that what you did here was to download a script off the web and run it on your system with root privileges. *This can easily be a bad idea* because you have no control over what the script does nor any guaranteed way to repeat the installation. It's often better to use prepackaged binaries; in the case of Ubuntu, those would be provided as one or more `.deb` files that you install using `dpkg -i filename.deb`, or if the software is available in the repository (better) can be installed through tools like aptitude, synaptic, apt-get, the Ubuntu Application Center, or some variant thereof.

Comment: I just wanted to know whether a similar (a script) rollback option for the SIFT Workstation.